# Jquery animation for exchanging the position of two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, path, jquery-animate

I have two elements whose position and size I am trying to exchange on click of the second element only

```
<div id="card-1" class="1">
    Some Content for 1
</div>

<div id="card-2" class="2">
    Some Content for 2
</div>
```

using jquery path js

```
$(document).on('click', '.2', function(){
    var path_1 = {
        start: { 
          x: 0, 
          y: 0, 
          angle: -120
        },  
        end: { 
          x:0,
          y:360, 
          angle: -120, 
          length: 0.25
        }
    }

    var path_2 = {
        start: { 
          x: 0, 
          y: 0, 
          angle: -180
        },  
        end: { 
          x:0,
          y:-360, 
          angle: -60, 
          length: 0.25
        }
    }

    $(".1").animate({
        width: "-=50%",
        path : new $.path.bezier(path_1)
    }, 2500);


    $(".2").animate({
        width: "+=100%",
        path : new $.path.bezier(path_2)
    }, 2500);

    var x = $('.2').attr('id');
    var y = $('.1').attr('id');

    $('#'+ x +',#'+ y +'').toggleClass('2 1');
});
```

Then I exchange the classes as you can see in the last 3 lines of code to get the same effect.

The first time when i click on #card-2 (class 2), the position and size gets exchanged, and also the classes are toggled for the divs but, the when I click on #card-1 (class 2), I do not get the same effect. How do get the same effect again?

This is how my page looks at first
[image]

I want #div1 to shrink and go to where #div2 is currently and #div2 to grow and reach where #div1 is currently on click of #div2. Something like this
[image]

This is happening. but thin I want the divs to get back to their original position on click of #div1. Something like this.
[image]
But this is not happening.

I have used classes for the animation and so after first step, I am exchanging the classes. But instead I am getting this type of result
[image]

Comment: Not able to understand your exact requirement, can you please elaborate.

Comment: Refer this https://jsfiddle.net/vfdfvrcx/7/, maybe it will help you.